# Exporting Large data record into excel sheet using Node.js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, excel, export-to-excel, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to export large data records into excel sheets like .xlsx, .xls, .csv,etc. I am using xlsx and file-saver for exporting. For 155000 records, its working fine and successfully exported my data into excel sheet, but for 160000 records, node.js and react.js unable to export those data records. I tried everything i could to solve these. I think node.js has limitation on exporting such kind of data

Here is the code for exporting data into excel:

```
const express = require("express");
const fileSaver = require('file-saver');
const XLSX = require('xlsx')
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cors());

const data = [];
let names = ["Danys", "Daood", "Dara", "Darach", "Daragh", "Darcy", "D'arcy", "Dareh", "Daren", "Darien", "Darius", "Darl", "Darn", "Darrach", "Darragh", "Darrel", "Darrell", "Darren", "Darrie", "Darrius", "Darroch", "Darryl", "Darryn", "Darwyn", "Daryl", "Daryn", "Daud", "Daumantas", "Davi", "David", "David-Jay", "David-Lee", "Davie", "Davis", "Davy", "Dawid", "Dawson", "Dawud", "Dayem",]
let age = [21, 24, 26, 28, 35, 40, 22];
const fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';

function randomRet(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
console.log('data', new Date());

for (let i = 0; i < 150000; i++) {
    const object = {
        id: i,
        key1: `Value ${i}`,
        key2: `Another Value ${i}`,
        height: "4 feet",
        weight: "30 pounds",
        color: "brown",
        material: "wood",
        name: randomRet(names),
        age: randomRet(age),
        address: 'faker.address.streetAddress()',
        phone: 'faker.phone.phoneNumber()',
        email: 'faker.internet.email()',
        city: "New York",
        r_code: "R00001",
        Column_1: "Column_1",
        Column_2: randomRet(age),
        Column_3: "Column_3",
        Column_4: "Column_14",
        Column_5: "Column_51",
        Column_6: "Column_6",
        Column_7: "Column_7",
        Column_8: "Column_8",
        Column_9: "Column_9",
        Column_10: "Column_10",
        Column_11: "Column_11",
        Column_12: "Column_21",
        Column_13: "Column_13",
        Column_14: "Column_14",
        Column_15: "Column_15",
        Column_16: "Column_16",
        Column_17: "Column_117",
        Column_18: "Column_81",
        Column_19: "Column_19",
        Column_20: "Column_20",
        Column_31: "Column_1",
        Column_32: "Column_2",
        Column_33: "Column_3",
        Column_34: "Column_14",
        Column_35: "Column_51",
        Column_36: "Column_6",
        Column_37: "Column_7",
        Column_38: "Column_8",
        Column_39: "Column_9",
        Column_40: "Column_10",
        Column_41: "Column_11",
        Column_42: "Column_21",
        Column_43: "Column_13",
        Column_44: "Column_14",
        Column_45: "Column_15",
        Column_46: "Column_16",
        Column_47: "Column_117",
        Column_48: "Column_81",
        Column_49: "Column_19",
        Column_50: "Column_20"
    };
    data.push(object);
}


// Define columns
const columns = [
    { header: "id", key: "id", width: 15 },
    { header: "key1", key: "key1", width: 10 },
    { header: "key2", key: "key2", width: 10 },
    { header: "height", key: "height", width: 15 },
    { header: "weight", key: "weight", width: 10 },
    { header: "color", key: "color", width: 15 },
    { header: "material", key: "material", width: 10 },
    { header: "name", key: "name", width: 15 },
    { header: "age", key: "age", width: 10 },
    { header: "address", key: "address", width: 15 },
    { header: "phone", key: "phone", width: 10 },
    { header: "email", key: "email", width: 10 },
    { header: "city", key: "city", width: 15 },
    { header: "r_code", key: "r_code", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_1", key: "Column_1", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_2", key: "Column_2", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_3", key: "Column_3", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_4", key: "Column_4", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_5", key: "Column_5", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_6", key: "Column_6", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_7", key: "Column_7", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_8", key: "Column_8", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_9", key: "Column_9", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_10", key: "Column_10", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_11", key: "Column_11", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_12", key: "Column_12", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_13", key: "Column_13", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_14", key: "Column_14", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_15", key: "Column_15", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_16", key: "Column_16", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_17", key: "Column_17", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_18", key: "Column_18", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_19", key: "Column_19", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_20", key: "Column_20", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_31", key: "Column_31", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_32", key: "Column_32", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_33", key: "Column_33", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_34", key: "Column_34", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_35", key: "Column_35", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_36", key: "Column_36", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_37", key: "Column_37", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_38", key: "Column_38", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_39", key: "Column_39", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_40", key: "Column_40", width: 10 },

    { header: "Column_41", key: "Column_41", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_42", key: "Column_42", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_43", key: "Column_43", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_44", key: "Column_44", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_45", key: "Column_45", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_46", key: "Column_46", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_47", key: "Column_47", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_48", key: "Column_48", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_49", key: "Column_49", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_50", key: "Column_50", width: 10 },

];

const dataCol = [columns.map(col => { return col.header })];

console.log(dataCol)

app.get("/export", (req, res) => {
    const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data,{
        origin: 'A2',
        skipHeader: true,
    });
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, dataCol);
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb,ws,'Sheet');
    const buffer = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer'});
    res.attachment('Sheet.xlsx');
    return res.send(buffer);

});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

So as per my code, I tried to export those data using XLSX and file-saver. I also tried by using sheetjs-style and streamsaver.js by streaming first and exporting after. But that is also giving me the same issue

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require("express");
const fileSaver = require('file-saver');
const XLSX = require('xlsx')
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const cluster = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

app.use(cors());

const data = [];
let names = ["Danys", "Daood", "Dara", "Darach", "Daragh", "Darcy", "D'arcy", "Dareh", "Daren", "Darien", "Darius", "Darl", "Darn", "Darrach", "Darragh", "Darrel", "Darrell", "Darren", "Darrie", "Darrius", "Darroch", "Darryl", "Darryn", "Darwyn", "Daryl", "Daryn", "Daud", "Daumantas", "Davi", "David", "David-Jay", "David-Lee", "Davie", "Davis", "Davy", "Dawid", "Dawson", "Dawud", "Dayem",]
let age = [21, 24, 26, 28, 35, 40, 22];
const fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';

function randomRet(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}
console.log('data', new Date());

for (let i = 0; i < 150000; i++) {
    const object = {
        id: i,
        key1: `Value ${i}`,
        key2: `Another Value ${i}`,
        height: "4 feet",
        weight: "30 pounds",
        color: "brown",
        material: "wood",
        name: randomRet(names),
        age: randomRet(age),
        address: 'faker.address.streetAddress()',
        phone: 'faker.phone.phoneNumber()',
        email: 'faker.internet.email()',
        city: "New York",
        r_code: "R00001",
        Column_1: "Column_1",
        Column_2: randomRet(age),
        Column_3: "Column_3",
        Column_4: "Column_14",
        Column_5: "Column_51",
        Column_6: "Column_6",
        Column_7: "Column_7",
        Column_8: "Column_8",
        Column_9: "Column_9",
        Column_10: "Column_10",
        Column_11: "Column_11",
        Column_12: "Column_21",
        Column_13: "Column_13",
        Column_14: "Column_14",
        Column_15: "Column_15",
        Column_16: "Column_16",
        Column_17: "Column_117",
        Column_18: "Column_81",
        Column_19: "Column_19",
        Column_20: "Column_20",
        Column_31: "Column_1",
        Column_32: "Column_2",
        Column_33: "Column_3",
        Column_34: "Column_14",
        Column_35: "Column_51",
        Column_36: "Column_6",
        Column_37: "Column_7",
        Column_38: "Column_8",
        Column_39: "Column_9",
        Column_40: "Column_10",
        Column_41: "Column_11",
        Column_42: "Column_21",
        Column_43: "Column_13",
        Column_44: "Column_14",
        Column_45: "Column_15",
        Column_46: "Column_16",
        Column_47: "Column_117",
        Column_48: "Column_81",
        Column_49: "Column_19",
        Column_50: "Column_20"
    };
    data.push(object);
}


// Define columns
const columns = [
    { header: "id", key: "id", width: 15 },
    { header: "key1", key: "key1", width: 10 },
    { header: "key2", key: "key2", width: 10 },
    { header: "height", key: "height", width: 15 },
    { header: "weight", key: "weight", width: 10 },
    { header: "color", key: "color", width: 15 },
    { header: "material", key: "material", width: 10 },
    { header: "name", key: "name", width: 15 },
    { header: "age", key: "age", width: 10 },
    { header: "address", key: "address", width: 15 },
    { header: "phone", key: "phone", width: 10 },
    { header: "email", key: "email", width: 10 },
    { header: "city", key: "city", width: 15 },
    { header: "r_code", key: "r_code", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_1", key: "Column_1", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_2", key: "Column_2", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_3", key: "Column_3", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_4", key: "Column_4", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_5", key: "Column_5", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_6", key: "Column_6", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_7", key: "Column_7", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_8", key: "Column_8", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_9", key: "Column_9", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_10", key: "Column_10", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_11", key: "Column_11", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_12", key: "Column_12", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_13", key: "Column_13", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_14", key: "Column_14", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_15", key: "Column_15", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_16", key: "Column_16", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_17", key: "Column_17", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_18", key: "Column_18", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_19", key: "Column_19", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_20", key: "Column_20", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_31", key: "Column_31", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_32", key: "Column_32", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_33", key: "Column_33", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_34", key: "Column_34", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_35", key: "Column_35", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_36", key: "Column_36", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_37", key: "Column_37", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_38", key: "Column_38", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_39", key: "Column_39", width: 15 },
    { header: "Column_40", key: "Column_40", width: 10 },

    { header: "Column_41", key: "Column_41", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_42", key: "Column_42", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_43", key: "Column_43", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_44", key: "Column_44", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_45", key: "Column_45", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_46", key: "Column_46", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_47", key: "Column_47", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_48", key: "Column_48", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_49", key: "Column_49", width: 10 },
    { header: "Column_50", key: "Column_50", width: 10 },

];

const dataCol = [columns.map(col => { return col.header })];

console.log(dataCol)

app.get("/export", (req, res) => {
    const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data,{
        origin: 'A2',
        skipHeader: true,
    });
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, dataCol);
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb,ws,'Sheet');
    const buffer = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer'});
    res.attachment('Sheet.xlsx');
    return res.send(buffer);

});

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Master process, fork workers
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    });
} else {
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
}
```

I have Modified your code to take levrage of all available cpu cores this will parrallise the task and increase the application performance

Comment: Its not working...

Comment: I tried same code in react.js. But i am facing the same issue. Chrome is not able to export more than 160000 records into excel sheet. The record has 160000 rows and 55 columns. But in firefox i am able to export 300000 data records.

Comment: Chrome is not able to reaching its maximum memory consumption while exporting more than 160000 records. but below that its memory consumption goes beyond 4000 mb...! Same goes for firefox

Comment: Its not about browser , Its about memory utlisition,  write a node service which read and write data in excel in chunk of 10 k, and free up memory after each loop by setting hevy object variable to null/0. dont proceed all data at once proces the data in chunk in while loop